# Limit UITextField to Int input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to determine if the input of a given type of `UITextField` is an Int. No matter what character I input into said field, I get back:

> input isn't a number

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let numberField = textField as? NumberField {
        print("type is numberField")
        if Int(numberField.text!) != nil {
            print("input is a number")
            typoFrequencySaveOut.isEnabled = true
            typoFrequencySaveOut.backgroundColor = .green
            return true
        } else {
            print("input isn't a number")
            typoFrequencySaveOut.isEnabled = false
            typoFrequencySaveOut.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            return false
        }
    }
    print("type is not number field")
    return true
}
```

How else can I identify what data type is being entered into a UITextField?

Comment: Are you sure the text you check contains only numbers and not additional characters? This code should work and is working for me.

Comment: Why not you change the keyboard type to take only numbers `numpad`?

Comment: @Eilon yes, the field is empty.

Comment: @SureshMopidevi that doesn't prevent an iPad from changing keyboards or someone from pasting text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check **the input** not entire text:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    ...
    var isEnglishNumber: Bool { return Int(string) != nil }
    print(isEnglishNumber ? "isEnglishNumber" : "isNOTEnglishNumber")
    ...
    return isEnglishNumber
}
```

Note that I removed codes that are not related to the original question, you can use the computed var `isEnglishNumber` in any way you like.

Comment: Then how can I call this method only on UITextFields I want to restrict? The method is called for all UITextFields in the controller. I'm not sure what you mean by unrelated text field either. The custom class I'm referencing is just inheriting from UITextField and is just a way for me to identify fields I want to contain numbers so I can work with them appropriately. Also, the check for type passes

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that you use custom class to detect the delegate. But the point was to check **the input only** and it stays the same. I updated the code.